# How do I separate a commit into a branch after doing several other commits?

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

I have a Git repo with the following structure:

```
A--B--C--D--E
```

I’d like to separate the C commit into a branch:

```
     C
    / \
A--B---D--E
```

How do I do that?

Comment: The `B---D` line is probably extraneous — you’re not rewriting any commits, just renaming things.

Comment: If the new branch is to be long lived and synced up with the current one, the B--D line may be desirable. Depends on what you want.

Comment: @adymitruk No, I mean D does not have B as a parent, so the two graphs are of different histories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git branch new-branch C
```

will create a new branch pointing to `C` named `new-branch`, ending up with this:

```
    new-branch     HEAD
          |         |
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

Comment: does not produce the graph that was desired in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is to honour the fact that D has 2 parents in the output that you want. I'm going to assume E is being pointed to by master.

```
git branch new-branch C
git checkout -b merge-base B
git merge --no-ff new-branch
git rebase --onto merge-base D^ master
git checkout master
```

you will end up with this:

```
     C
    / \
A--B---Y--D'--E'
```

this will preserve C as a parent in a merge into the main branch. You could squash D into Y with git rebase -i head^^^. You would then have:

```
     C
    / \
A--B---D''--E''
```